# Is it possible to set a discovery URI for token acquisition in Microsoft.Identity.Web?

Tags: c#, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform, microsoft-identity-web

I have a .NET5 app that is utilizing Microsoft.Identity.Web for a secure API.  When attempting to retrieve the access token:

```
var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForAppAsync(scopesToAccessDownstreamApi);
```

The first thing that happens is it makes a request to the discovery endpoint:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/instance?api-version=1.1&authorization_endpoint=.......%2Fauthorize
```

I have a static authority specified in my config which I thought it should be using instead.  For my Blazor app it works just fine.  MS.Identity.Web first gets my key information at my authority:

```
https://myCustomAuthority/myTenantId/oauth2/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

With the tokenAcquisition however, it always calls login.microsoft.com, fails, and then finally redirects to my endpoint.

Digging through both the MS.Identity.Web and MS.Identity.Client code they definitely had this in mind.

```
/// Allows developers to configure their own valid authorities. A json string similar to https://aka.ms/aad-instance-discovery should be provided.
```

See here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/blob/ac7541c1aa1c7bdbb20df5c7e72628161f826f44/src/client/Microsoft.Identity.Client/AppConfig/AbstractApplicationBuilder.cs#L51

```
        public InstanceDiscoveryResponse CustomInstanceDiscoveryMetadata { get; set; }
    public Uri CustomInstanceDiscoveryMetadataUri { get; set; }
```

And here:
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/blob/ac7541c1aa1c7bdbb20df5c7e72628161f826f44/src/client/Microsoft.Identity.Client/AppConfig/ApplicationConfiguration.cs#L95

But I'm unable to find it on the API side.  And when I look at TokenAquisition it's calling ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.CreateWithApplicationOptions

```
                var builder = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                    .CreateWithApplicationOptions(_applicationOptions)
                    .WithHttpClientFactory(_httpClientFactory);
```

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/b106d9a9250522d0bf9ed0e78e0e3dbd376d8170/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web/TokenAcquisition.cs#L583

Which then creates a new ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder with an empty ApplicationConfiguration object so the CustomInstanceDiscovery is always null

```
            var config = new ApplicationConfiguration();
        var builder = new ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder(config).WithOptions(options);
```

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/blob/ac7541c1aa1c7bdbb20df5c7e72628161f826f44/src/client/Microsoft.Identity.Client/AppConfig/ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.cs#L42

All the hooks seem to be there so I feel like I'm missing some configuration but it also could be a feature / bug request.

Comment: Do you mean `Microsoft.Identity.Web`?  If not, what is `MS.Identity.Web`.  You have a lot of characters in your question, spelling out a key search term would make it easier for your readers to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

This was an actual defect that the Microsoft.Identity.Web team has fixed.  I asked the same question to the team:
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/discussions/1202

And they created an issue:
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/1212

So this was fixed with build 1.13.